# Folder in gitignore should be not grayed out when added to workspace manually

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

[image: Structure]

Given a workspace which has two folders: a parent folder and a subfolder, when the parent folder has the subfolder in `.gitignore` the other folder added on the same workspace folder hierarchy level is grayed out. Is it possible to make it not grayed out just via vscode config without changing the gitignore or using symlinks?

Comment: my first thought is its a bug, but thats just a guess. I can see what you say about it not working as expected.

Comment: perhaps add a blank .gitignore to the workspace root?